# React how do I export the params of a component from another library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, package, rollup, tsconfig

I am creating my own package, within this package I created the following component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Player, PlayerProps, PlayerRef } from '@remotion/player'
import { ReactElement, RefAttributes } from 'react'
import { TemplateProps } from '../../types'

export type MyPlayerProps = PlayerProps<TemplateProps> & RefAttributes<PlayerRef>

export const MyPlayer = (props: MyPlayerProps): ReactElement => {
  return <Player {...props} />
}
```

when I use this component of mine in my projects the properties do not automatically appear; this only happens to me when I create components that I extend from an external package.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please show us how you're attempting to consume them? This should work just fine